# How do security questions work?

Tags: authentication, web-application, appsec, secret-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do security questions subvert passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/do-security-questions-subvert-passwords)

Is it true that on some websites (e.g.: free webmail) there are "security questions" - if the user forgets about his password he could answer the security question, that he provided before, and then he could change his password. BUT: isn't this a security issue? What happens when the security question is weak, and guessable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually **security questions are not used by themselves** and are used to accompany email verification. Some services also use them when your logging in from a different location to normal to add to the login process. Using them by themselves, unless you're asking like 50 questions, can be a security issue.

Whatever you do they can still be weak and guessable so the right questions have to be used. There is a **list of good security questions [here](http://www.goodsecurityquestions.com/examples.htm)** which are supposed to be more difficult to guess.